# c# classification inside datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I don't know exactly what is the correct term/way to explain my question but i hope someone get my idea

My datatable are required to classify few type of sources (ex in image) and i need to calculate them according to the type.. is there any way i can perform this?

Thank you so much for your reply

Here's what i've tried so far

```
  for (int l = 0; l < my_datatable.Rows.Count; l++)
        {

            data_source = my_datatable.Rows[l][3].ToString();

            if (data_source.Contains("Cross Site Scripting"))
            {
                my_datatable.Rows[l][3] = "2";
            }
            else if (data_source.Contains("SQL Injection"))
            {
                my_datatable.Rows[l][3] = "3";
            }
            else if (data_source.Contains("Unicode Attack"))
            {
                my_datatable.Rows[l][3] = "4";
            }
            else if (data_source.Contains("Proxy Attack"))
            {
                my_datatable.Rows[l][3] = "5";
            }
            else
            {
                my_datatable.Rows[l][3] = "1";
            }
```

current output

[image: current output]

expected output

[image: expected output]

Code for CSV part

```
        string[] raw_text = 
        System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\dummylog3.csv"); //Placement of the 
        .CSV Files
        string[] data_col = null;
        int x = 0;

        foreach (string text_line in raw_text)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(text_line);
            data_col = text_line.Split(' ');

            if (x == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= data_col.Count() - 1; i++)
                {
                    my_datatable.Columns.Add(data_col[i]);
                }

                x++;
            }
            else
            {

                my_datatable.Rows.Add(data_col);
            }

            my_datagridview.DataSource = my_datatable;
            this.Controls.Add(my_datagridview);
        }
```

Comment: You are going row by row and you keep setting the 4th column of the table to a value. That is what you are doing in your code. What are you trying to achieve? Where is the data coming from?

Comment: Yea. Ive set the column to a value.. the data is coming from a server log (.csv file) where i seperate those into 9 column.. what am trying to achieve is to class/sort the source type file and calculate them like second image. @CodingYoshi

Comment: Can you post some sample lines from the csv?

Comment: sorry, i meant the log it self and not how you read it.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gSwJhrH.jpg @Ephraim

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom class which inherits the DataTable

```
   public class CustomDataTable : DataTable 
    {
        public enum ClassificationType
        {
            IMAGE
        }
        public ClassificationType classification { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure how this is going to achieve what the OP wants. What is `IMAGE` and why is this needed?

Comment: It is exactly what the OP needs. IMAGE is just a type.  The OP will add a new enum for each type of DataTable.  The variable classification will be set when each datatable is constructed.  Then when the table is used the variable will be tested to determine type before any calculations are performed.

Comment: Hi, if so can you provide a little more of hint cause im getting lose with the customdatatable function

Comment: All I'm really doing is adding one additional property to the standard DataTable class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project has a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`, if not then add it. You will need this to call 'CopyToDataTable` extension method.

Create a table for your summarized data. We will just use this to create new rows for the summary table. But the data will not be stored here. See next point:

```
var summary = new DataTable();
summary.Columns.Add("Code");
summary.Columns.Add("Source Type");
summary.Columns.Add("Number Of Hits", typeof(int));
```

Using Linq, the code below will group the results by the `Code` and `Source Type` and then find the count of them. It will finally copy the data to a `DataTable`:

```
var result =
    table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => new { Code = x["Code"], SourceType = x["Source Type"] })
    .Select(x => summary.Rows.Add(x.Key.Code, x.Key.SourceType, x.Count()))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Hi, can you give me a hint on how can i do the count cause my output is 1 for every source type :[

Comment: In the result query I had `table`, did you change that to `my_datatable`?

Comment: yeah, i did change the table = my_datatable, but still cant figure out why it wont add up the type of source.. :/ sorry mate.

Comment: @AliffM. You need to create sample of your data and provide it to me so I can test my code against it and tell you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1a8nanJ0-O69ezunCyUbc0GgWiWqaeD-OdHbeX35Vnn8 Hi this is my sample data, i use space for the delimiter to seperate them into column. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4TlBPpyefJFdTdzNXViQnVtNGs this is also my full code, hope you get the idea of my full program.

Comment: @AliffM. I looked at your code and your file but it's not clear what you want the result to be. Please put the data into a table and based on the data let me know what the summary should be. I will then help you with the code.

Comment: Hi @codingyoshi, im still working on this but i still cant figure it out, i screenshot how my program works 1) http://i.imgur.com/7QLgJgM.jpg 2) http://i.imgur.com/xe4bCYK.jpg 3) http://i.imgur.com/CSCp1Vb.jpg  - basically what i wanted to achieve is to calculate back the discrete values and display properly in a table (it will calculate the total of resource based on the discreted values) I wanted to know how can achieve as image #3. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @AliffM. Please tell me why the number of hits is 21 (how did you get that number) and what is `Source Type` and `Code`. I need to know which columns those are in your table because in your table those columns do not exist. By table I mean the datatable in your code. I need to know which column you want to summarize and what you want the summary by.

Comment: I'm sorry that is just a dummy table, supposedly it will give result = 29. it should be able to do calculation at column = "source" where the total of normal is 29 (similar to image #3). What i meant in summary is to display similar like image #3, it will display the total number from different source (the value will get from source in image #2)

Comment: 1) this is my latest code, i just leave code in summary button into blank (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4TlBPpyefJFa29GTDNqVmo3akE) 2- my testing data (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4TlBPpyefJFX1VHYnUxMWZBS28)

Comment: i really had no idea on how to calculate it, i hope you can help me on that part cause this is my internship project :[